# Get the document id of all documents in couchdb database

Tags: get, couchdb

I have a simple question, How should I retrieve the document ids of all documents from a given database in couchdb.

I have written this code which retrieves all the documents-

```
     docs=CouchRest.get("http://localhost:5984/competency1/_all_docs?include_docs=true")
     puts docs.to_json
```

The above code displays the entire details of the database.I want to be able to list only the document id's.

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

From [HTTP Document API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API) about retrieving all documents:

> To get a listing of all documents in a database, use the special
>   _all_docs URI. ... Will return a listing of all documents and their
>   revision IDs, ordered by DocID (case sensitive)

In other words, get `/competency1/_all_docs` **without** the `?include_docs=true` part. This is the best solution for several reasons.

1. Like a map/reduce view, it supports `limit`, `startkey,`endkey` options.
2. But *unlike* a map/reduce view, it does not use any additional disk space or CPU.
3. Other people (or you in the future) will immediately recognize this query's purpose.

Comment: +1 Your answer is right. I took the liberty of tightening it up and listing some advantages. Hope you don't mind.