# Get all ids in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Is there a good way to get all ids in a database in CouchDB? I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568717/get-the-document-id-of-all-documents-in-couchdb-database), but it seems kind of hackish and there must be a better way.

If I did use that solution, how well would it scale? How long would it take to find the ids of say, all 100,000 documents in a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution from that question is the best answer. (I just edited it to make it more clear.)

Your concern that it feels hackish is valid. However, using `_all_docs` is worthwhile. Firstly, it is very efficient and scalable. The list of document IDs is already stored in CouchDB. Fetching 100,000 ids (**without** `?include_docs=true` of course) would be very fast.

Secondly, rather than, say a plain text list, the `_all_docs` response provides enough structure (the JSON rows) to be useful in the long-term. (It won't be long until you want batches of 1,000, or only ids beginning with "m", etc.)

Comment: Thanks :D I think I will go with that route!